# A splash of Minecraft?

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, cipher, lateral-thinking, acrostic

I was playing Minecraft the other day and came across a beautiful splash message. Subsequently, I was inspired to create a puzzle for it.

---

> Svir, look out below!
>
> Shorty's slang stays surprisingly stout.
>
> F-B is surely Newton's demise.
>
> How many blind mice? they/?.
>
> Once upon a time... Have you seen it? Add one... Don't give up!
>
> Sicks, I got them on sale. Do they make me look fat?

What's next?

---

Hints:

> 1: Each line serves two purposes... Well, all but two, which is one.
>  2: The lines are out of order, I suspect there are clues on how to correct it.

---

<sub>***Note**: Be sure to [check your answer](https://minecraft-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Splash_Texts)!*</sub>

<sub>***Edit**: I just found out, this is my 100<sup>th</sup> question on Puzzling.SE!*</sub>

Comment: rot13(V qba'g frr ubj Arjgba unf nalguvat gb qb jvgu yvar 3, fb znlor vg'f na nantenz?)